# trying to update a row from one table to another

Tags: sql, teradata

```
UPDATE customer_service.batch_status.cust_nm
SET batch_status.cust_nm
SELECT customer_service.batch_detail.cust_nm 
FROM   customer_service.batch_detail 
LEFT JOIN customer_service.batch_status 
    ON customer_service.batch_detail.cust_nm = customer_service.batch_status.cust_nm;
```

Comment: And, do you have any question?

Comment: Trying to update BATCH_STATUS.cust_nm from BATCH_DETAIL. cust_nm.

Comment: It is popping up an error with "syntax error, expected something like a name or Unicode delimited identifier between the word batch_status and .."

Comment: Are you sure Teradata supports that UPDATE FROM syntax?

Comment: I'm new to teradata and sql. just playing around with it :)

Comment: Missing `=` for the SET.

Comment: That is not valid Teradata syntax at all. Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987152/teradata-update-table-from-select-statement).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off.

Instead:

```
UPDATE customer_service.batch_status.cust_nm
FROM customer_service.batch_detail csbd
SET cust_nm = csbd.cust_nm
WHERE csbd.cust_nm = customer_service.batch_status.cust_nm;
```