# Is it possible to update one table from another table without a join in Vertica?

Tags: sql, database, sql-update, vertica

I have two tables A(i,j,k) and B(m,n).

I want to update the 'm' column of B table by taking sum(j) from table A. Is it possible to do it in Vertica?

Following code can be used for Teradata, but does Vertica have this kind of flexibility?

```
Update B from (select sum(j) as m from A)a1 set m=a1.m;
```

Comment: This is a slightly peculiar syntax, User3503711, so I'm trying to figure out what you're expecting it to do. `UPDATE <table> FROM ... ` is not a standard SQL syntax. Looks like you want the column `m` in all rows in Table `B` to assume the value you get when you `SUM(j)` in table `A`. Is that right?

Comment: That is a Teradata SQL syntax. Similar syntax are posted [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987152/teradata-update-table-from-select-statement) .And Yes, that's what I want to do. Sum(j) from table A will be copied to m column of table B. - @marcothesane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Teradata SQL syntax won't work with Vertica, but the following query should do the same thing :

```
update B set m = (select sum(j) from A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your tables, this may not be an efficient way to update data.   Vertical is a WORM (write once read many times) store, and is not optimized for updates or deletes.

An alternate way would be to first temporarily move the data in the target table to another intermediate (but not temporary) table.  After that write a join query using the other table to produce the desired result, and finally use `export table` with that join query.  Finally drop the intermediate table.  Of course, this is assuming you have partitioned your table in a way suitable for your update logic.