# how to add data to a column from another table if there are duplicates

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to insert into SBX.COR to Prefix column data from Prefix from SBX.HEX for specific matches, on my request

```
update SBX.COR sc
set Prefix = (
select Prefix 
    from SBX.HEX sfh
        where sc.Car = sfh.Car
        and sc.Opex = sfh.Opex
        and sc.Reg = sfh.Reg)
```

outputs More than one value was returned by a subquery

how can I correct the request?

update:
i want to add in table SBX.COR Opex and Reg from SBX.HEX, but in SBX.COR there are duplicates, for example:

```
table SBX.COR
Car Opex    Reg Prefix  Events
rtk mts     msc     
vk  mts     msc 

table SBX.HEX
Car Opex    Reg Prefix  Events
rtk mts     msc 7916    1119
vk  mts     msc 7916    1119
```

Comment: You may refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987152/teradata-update-table-from-select-statement

Comment: You need to determine how to identify only the rows you want.  Lots of different approaches to this.  Add some sample data and desired results to your post.

Comment: Depending on your data it might be a simple `select MAX(Prefix)...` to return a single row.

Comment: select MAX() add only one value, and I need all

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE sbx.cor sc
USING sbx.hex sfh
ON sc.car = sfh.car AND sc.opex = sfh.opex AND sc.reg = sfh.reg
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET sc.prefix = sfh.prefix
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try your update with a slight mod:

```
update SBX.COR sc
set Prefix = (
select unique Prefix 
    from SBX.HEX sfh
        where sc.Car = sfh.Car
        and sc.Opex = sfh.Opex
        and sc.Reg = sfh.Reg)
```